# Regression-Interpretation of a constant

Tags: multiple-regression

I am inquiring as to why an intercept/constant in a regression would increase if a variable is controlled for?

Answer (score 0):

a 1 unit increase in X yields an __ unit increase in Y while controlling for "covariate".